# Transition between spin-up and spin-down states in magnetic resonance

Tags: quantum-spin

What is the classification of the transition between spin‐up and spin‐down states in magnetic 
resonance (such as NMR, ESR, MRI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NMR (Nuclear Magnetic Resonance) and MRI are both based on the same transitions, transtions between spin states of nuclei in a magnetic field.  These states are not limited to up and down.  Where $I$ is the spin of the nucleus, there will be states $m = -I, -I + 1, -I + 2 ... I$ So if the nucleus is $I=0$ one can't do NMR on the nucleus.  If $I=1/2$, then there will be two states, $m = -1/2$ and $m = +1/2$.  Most common, NMR is done on $I=1/2$ nuclei such as protons and carbon-13, in which case spin up and spin down is applicable, but NMR is also done on deuterium and other nuclie that are not $I=1/2$.

ESR (Electron Spin Resonance) is based on transitions between spin states of electrons in a magnetic field.